# Unexpected ouput when trying to find minimum value in an array using x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a beginner following a book (Programming from the ground up) and this is my first assembly program:

```
.section .data

data_items: .long 3, 67, 34, 222, 45, 75, 54, 34, 44, 33, 22, 11, 66, 0

.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx

start_loop:
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit
    incl %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
    cmpl %ebx, %eax
    jge start_loop
    movl %eax, %ebx
    jmp start_loop

loop_exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

`%edi` is used the keep track of the current index, `%eax` of the current value and `%ebx` of the current highest value.

This program originally found the highest value by jumping back if `%eax` was less than `%ebx` (meaning it didn't have to store the new value as the current highest) and I just changed it to `jge` instead of `jle` so it would only store `%eax` in `%ebx` if it encountered a smaller value.

My issue is that my program returns `0` instead of `3`, which I expect would be the correct output. Shouldn't it exit when it encounters `0` because it checks if `%eax` is `0` at the start of every `start_loop` iteration and if so, jumps to `loop_exit`?

So in short: why is the output of this program `0` instead of `3`?

edit: by output I mean the return code of `%ebx` when I call `echo $?`

Comment: There is a 0 in data_items.  And yes, your code compares it.  And you never check the first item.  Those are called "bugs".  Make it work with two items first, use a debugger.  Then three.  Then four, by then you'll have the bugs sorted out.

Comment: Okay I'll look at it more closely in a bit, but when I change `jge` back to `jle` (the original) to find the maximum value it works perfectly, shouldn't there be bugs too then?

Comment: No, because your sentinel (`0`) isn't also the maximum.  **use a debugger to single-step** and watch register values change.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for gdb tips.  (@Hans, the code loads the first item outside the loop, instead of using INT_MAX as the starting value or something.)

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't it exit when it encounters 0 because it checks if %eax is 0 at the start of every start_loop iteration

So you want to treat 0 as your list terminating value. This requires you to check for it as soon as you read each value. Your code has 2 instances of such a read and so requires 2 checks for the terminating value:

```
    ...
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
    movl %eax, %ebx
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je   loop_exit     ;List is empty, only terminator present
start_loop:
    incl %edi
    movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
    cmpl $0, %eax
    je loop_exit       ;End of list reached
    ...
```

Comment: You could instead put the loading of the next element at the bottom of the loop (after the `min = min(min, new)` check).  That saves a branch outside the loop.  Anyway, the key point is checking for sentinel before considering it as a new min, but that doesn't *have* to be right away after loading it.